# Spring security. Custom AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I have spring mvc application. And i've added Spring Security with CustomAuthenticationManager. This is application-security.xml that included in appContex.xml. In login.jsp i use standart login page with 2 inputs: name='j_username' & name='j_password' and than in method in CustomAuthenticationManager.authenticate(Authentication authentication) i receive only password, but not principal with it name. What am i do wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="loginPassAuthenticationFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="customAuthenticationManager" />
    <property name="allowSessionCreation" value="true" />
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
</bean>

<bean id="customAuthenticationManager"
    class="com.whatever.security.CustomAuthenticationManager" />
<bean id="authenticationFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
    p:authenticationManager-ref="customAuthenticationManager"
    p:authenticationFailureHandler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
    p:authenticationSuccessHandler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

<bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
    p:defaultFailureUrl="/?error=true" />

<bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
    p:defaultTargetUrl="/" />

<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    p:loginFormUrl="/" />
<security:authentication-manager />
<bean id="passwordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="512" />
</bean>
```

```
<form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
    method='POST'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='j_password' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                value="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Your `j_username` input specifies its own `value=''`.  That may be pre-empting user-input values.

Comment: nope that's not helps

Comment: Hm, i placed logger into authetication manager and when i deploy app using eclipse it shows me in debug that any login was found, but if it was deployed using console on the real server - logger show me login...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to use Security Namespace (link to the example of minimal configuration):
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-minimal

Here the link how you can define your own authentication provider :
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-auth-manager

Creation of your own authentication provider solves most use cases. 
Please tell me if you need any additional clarifications.

Best regards,

Michael